# Does spring-security automatically disable CSRF when Authorization header (bearer jwt token) is used?

Tags: spring, spring-security, csrf, csrf-token

I have configured by spring boot application to work as an oauth2 resource server which expects JWT tokens in every request. Im seeing some behaviour with Spring Security such as below:

1. If I don't pass a JWT

```
curl -X POST  --data '{"somejson":"some data"}' --header "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080
```

The API gives a response like:

```
An expected CSRF token cannot be found
```

2. But If I pass the JWT tokenin authorization header like below request, then Spring doesn't complain about CSRF.

```
curl -X POST  --data '{"somejson":"some data"}' --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer JWTfirstpart.secondpart.thirdpart" http://localhost:8080
```

Does spring security automatically disable the CSRF check when the auth header is present?

My Spring security configuration looks like this

```
SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                        .anyExchange().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(ServerHttpSecurity.OAuth2ResourceServerSpec::jwt);
        return http.build();
    }
```

I constructed the configuration as per the spring docs here
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour is because of `OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer#registerDefaultCsrfOverride`. It doesn't apply the CSRF token validation to requests that contain a Bearer token, by using the BearerTokenRequestMatcher.

This is why, when I sent a JWT bearer token, no csrf check is applied, but when I don't send JWT bearer token, request fails with "CSRF token missing" error.

Sources:

1. This excellent answer to a related Question https://stackoverflow.com/a/71782433/4627552
2. Discussion on Spring security issues page https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8668

Answer (score 2):

I do not aware such behaviour. Base on the [codes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/c5063036db38f94f29212570d34010b260855ba4/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/server/csrf/CsrfWebFilter.java#L183) , by default it will disable CSRF for the `GET`,`HEAD`,`TRACE` and `OPTIONS` request only. There should be somewhere in your codes changes the related request matcher configuration.

You can set the breakpoints in the following codes for troubleshooting and see who change the request matcher.

- `CsrfWebFilter#setRequireCsrfProtectionMatcher()`
- `CsrfWebFilter#filter()`

Comment: Thank you! though this wasnt exactly what I was looking for, it was a good starting point to find the exact explanation. I have provided the final explanation of Spring's behaviour in another answer.